# Optimizing Execution Speed Advanced Filter Loop with Calculation of each record

Tags: performance, excel, cpu-speed, vba

Problem: Code executes at about 30 seconds per record. Need to optimize speed. Spreadsheet is built around 1 page of 100,000's of records, one record is compared to up-to 100 other records from the list using an advanced filter and lookups. Various adjustments are calculated and then values from calculation are returned back onto the "output page" for about 60,000 records. Issue is 60,000 records*30 seconds=500 hours. Thanks.

```
Sub EquityAutomated()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartNo As Long
    Dim EndNo As Long
    StartNo = InputBox("Enter the row on the Hsheet sheet you want the equity analysis to start on")
    EndNo = InputBox("Enter the row on the Hsheet sheet you want the equity analysis to end on")
    Dim wsProtestTest As Worksheet: Set wsProtestTest = Worksheets("ProtestTestData")
    Dim wsES As Worksheet:          Set wsES = Worksheets("EquitySpreadsheet")
    Dim wsEL As Worksheet:          Set wsEL = Worksheets("EquityList")
    Dim wsDa As Worksheet:          Set wsDa = Worksheets("Res")
    Dim subTotalsDa As Range:       Set subTotalsDa = wsDa.Range("A10:A647649")
    Dim fltrRng As Range:           Set fltrRng = wsDa.Range("A9:T647649")
    Dim fltrCritRng As Range:       Set fltrCritRng = wsDa.Range("A1:T2")
    Dim valRngDa As Range:          Set valRngDa = wsDa.Range("T10:T647649")
    Dim fullSrtRng As Range:        Set fullSrtRng = wsDa.Range("A9:S647649")
    Dim sortValRng As Range:        Set sortValRng = wsDa.Range("T9")
    Dim fullSortRngVal As Range:    Set fullSortRngVal = wsDa.Range("A10:T647649")
    Dim equityRankRng As Range:     Set equityRankRng = wsEL.Range("P5")
    Dim equityOutOfRng As Range:    Set equityOutOfRng = wsEL.Range("P4")
    Dim MedianRng As Range:         Set MedianRng = wsEL.Range("O6")
    Dim propValRng As Range:        Set propValRng = wsEL.Range("D5")
    Dim diffRng As Range:           Set diffRng = wsEL.Range("O7")
    Dim MinRng As Range:            Set MinRng = wsEL.Range("O8")
    Dim MaxRng As Range:            Set MaxRng = wsEL.Range("O9")
    Dim avgRng As Range:            Set avgRng = wsEL.Range("O10")
    Dim LogRng As Range:          Set LogRng = wsES.Range("B10")
    Dim Support3kLowerRng As Range:    Set Support3kLowerRng = wsEL.Range("O11")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = StartNo To EndNo
        LogRng = wsProtestTest.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value2
        subTotalsDa.ClearContents
        Application.Calculate
            If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
                DoEvents
            End If
        Application.Calculation = xlManual
        fltrRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
            CriteriaRange:=fltrCritRng, Unique:=False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.Calculate
        subTotalsDa.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=Subtotal(3,R10C2:RC[1])"
        valRngDa.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = _
            "=INDEX(EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GT$29,16,(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GS$12)+1))"
        With wsDa.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=valRngDa, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange fullSortRngVal
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
        With wsProtestTest
            .Cells(i + 2, 29) = equityRankRng: .Cells(i + 2, 30) = equityOutOfRng: .Cells(i + 2, 31) = Support3kLowerRng
            .Cells(i + 2, 32) = MedianRng:     .Cells(i + 2, 33) = propValRng
            .Cells(i + 2, 34) = diffRng:      .Cells(i + 2, 35) = MinRng
            .Cells(i + 2, 36) = MaxRng:       .Cells(i + 2, 37) = avgRng
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Edit:
Effectively what happens:
 1. Log is used to pull criteria for advanced filter.
 2. Adjusted value column is cleared (subtotals) to allow to be repopulated later after calc
 3. Advanced filter is ran using criteria from earlier
 4. After filter is ran the data in the returned cells are pulled into a sheet (subtotal is used to produce an identified for the index/match 1,2,3, etc. for each returned record). Index/match is used to populate various items of adjustment and then basic formulas are used to determine proper adjustment to subject(square footage, etc.)
 5. Various amounts are summed on the calc sheet to return an "indicated value." This then populates the "valRng" using the index match you see in the macro. 
 6. The filtered data is sorted low to high based on valRng.
 7. Values are brought onto the summary sheet for archiving, since the rest of the workbook updates with each new record. (With wsProtestTest section).

Comment: I appreciate the insight. I saw the array idea when I was digging around. However, I don't think it will work in my application. The obstacle is I need 100 records from the data set (comps) compared to 1 (subject). Values are then pulled into a calculation grid to adjust for comparability (using index/match and formulas to compare characteristics between the subject and comp). The adjusted values are then output onto another tab. An array seems to not accomplish this, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 647,649 records (the 100,000's from above). This has already been filtered to remove non-critical data (only needed rows and columns were kept).

Comment: Added a note to the bottom of original post to hopefully clarify what is going on.

Comment: The slow speed of your macro is inherent to the manner your workbook is set up. The sorting, filtering, calculating, reading and writing between VBA and Excel all take up a lot system resources. I at this point cannot think of a feasible solution for your problem without radically overhauling the entire workbook.

Comment: Is there a way I could do the computation with more resources then (cloud, upgrade computer, etc.)? The model works, it just has to calculate each time. Is there any small improvements you see in the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what the impact of upgrading your hardware would be or if Excel has cloud capabilities and I'm not going to advise on that. As far as the code goes I don't see quick fixes that would make a dent in the 500 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for me to understand your overall calculation process, but several things stand out as needing to be changed:

- Rather handling cells in a range one at a time (for example C6:C11) use a variant array
- Run the whole loop in Manual calculation mode and use application.Calculate as infrequently as possible.

  - Find an alternative way of achieving your desired results that does not involve sorting and filtering 650000 rows 60000 times!
  - INDIRECT is a volatile function and will slow down calculation: find a different way of doing the calculation that does not involve INDIRECT

Comment: I took your advice on the Indirect. I simplified it to:
        valRngDa.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = _
            "=INDEX(EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GT$29,16,RC[1]*2)"

Comment: However, I don't think the structure of the workbook allows for arrays or setting to a manual calculation mode. I outlined why above. Each time the records are returned calculations are done and archived before moving to the next iteration of the loop. Without a recalc in the loop the same value would be returned over and over again. If you have any other suggestions, I would appreciate it. I have brainstormed an alternative method, but can't seem to think of one (hints the question).

Comment: To clarify my original comments: A) set calculation to Manual and only use Application.Calculate every time you need the workbook to be recalculated.  B) look again at arrays - for example you can use an array for C6:C11 instead of individual variables and cells.   C) I find it hard to imagine that the somewhat unusual methodology you are using is the only possible way of solving the problem.

Comment: I am not seeing where I can use an array at. The calculation issue is explained above. There are calculations that are done using the returned data each time. If new data is returned, a new calc is needed. I have thought at length of alternatives and have not thought of anything. This might be due to my inexperience writing in vba. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have not understood that you are making Excel do at least 16 workbook recalculations for each iteration of your loop? And why do you think you cannot use an array for C6:C11?

Comment: I don't see where I even use the range C6:C11, maybe I am just blind. I will map out where I have to recalculate and see if I can minimize the calculations. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I think I understand the array comments, write the values to an array instead of to the worksheet inside the loop. Then outside the loop write the array to the worksheet. That makes sense. I can use a different array for each column without performance issues right? This would be to only have to deal with 1 dimensional arrays.

Comment: Improvements to calculation method cut the time by a third (10 seconds now).